# quickblox base Bad timestamp for 4.1.2

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm trying to start using Quickblox, since it provides great tools for backend. I have registered on website an got credentials for my app, however I fail to start simple program to test connection:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit("3504", "NMuekBBXBg6PgST", "HaOj5bY4LgxUpPH");

    QBAuth.createSession(new QBCallbackImpl() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Result result) {
            // result comes here
            // check if result success
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail :( " + result.getErrors(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

It works on AVD with Android 4.2.2 (API Level 17), however it fails on my galaxy s2 with 4.1.2 (API Level 16), with getErrors() returning "[base Bad timestamp]". I have no idea what I might be doing wrong, so any help would be appriciated. Please, don't make me switch to Parse :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is typical developers error and it's easy to fix it.

Bad timestamp means that while [Creating Session](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#API_Session_Creation) you sent invalid 'timestamp' value which is based on your phone time.

We suggest you synchronize time on your devices with NTP service or just set tick 2 checkboxes in Settings in your device: **Automatic date & time**  and **Automatic time zone**

Hope this help

Comment: I had set tick 2 checkboxes, still getting the error.

Comment: On some devices, notably the Samsung Tab 4, there is not an option in the Android settings for Automatic Time Zone.  (Obviously a flaw in Samsung's ROM).  In this unfortunate case, how can we deal with the bad timestamp error when the time isn't synchronized?

Answer (score -1):

Please check the official manual (page 89) where the time settings are described

[manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201505/20150518150653405/SM-T530_UM_EU_Lollipop_Eng_Rev.1.0_150513.pdf)

Comment: Instructing the user to look at their specific device manual does not seem to be a proper solution.  There would be no way to link it from within the application.