# Android Quickblox bad time stamp error

Tags: android

I am using Quickblox sdk for android, getting bad time stamp error. Is there any solution to resolve this error programatically except manually tick 2 checkboxes in Settings in your device: Automatic date & time and Automatic time zone.

Answer (score 2):

The error is related to developers.

Bad time stamp indicates that, while creating Session you sent invalid 'time stamp' value which is based on your device time.

Please, try to synchronize the  time on your devices with NTP service or just set tick 2 check boxes in in your device settings : Automatic date & time and Automatic time zone.

For more reference can follow this link.[Quickblox base Bad timestamp Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940482/quickblox-base-bad-timestamp-for-4-1-2)

Comment: after time sync still issue exsist.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred, when you are sending wrong invalid time stamp to quickblox server.This is depend on device time, so valid the time stamp of device, then this bug will automatically solved.